# Black-box optimization of a single parameter function with high cost evaluation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, global-optimization

I need to solve a series of single parameter black-box minimization problem. The underlying cost functions are quite simple. They always have the same shape: a global minimum inside a fixed interval (-15000; 15000).

The constraints are :

- The function is not differentiable;
- The function is slow to evaluate.

I can solve these problems using a coarse scan followed by a fine scan. But I need between 30 and 50 evaluations. I'm sure that there is a better way to do it, but I can't find how.

Two examples of these cost functions :

[image]
[image]

Comment: [NOMAD](https://www.gerad.ca/nomad/)

Comment: @Kuifje it seems a little too much for this type of problem. I was thinking of something more simple, as I only have 1 parameter to optimize and my function is always convex ...

Comment: @Kh4zit, have you faced with an optimization problem? or you are trying to work with a single equation?

Comment: Fibonacci search performs slightly better than golden search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your function is apparently unimodal (single local minimum, which is global), you might try [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search). The first four function evaluations result in about a 40% reduction in the initial interval. Each additional function thereafter again reduces the remaining interval by about 40%.

Comment: That's exactly the type of solution I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I would advise Bayesian Optimization. The benefits imho are that they don’t require a gradient, work for a wide variety of optimization problems and are made for when we are dealing with functions that are hard or slow to evaluate.